# Laravel+vue.js: using blade/php variable inside Vue variable in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

It might be a bit over engineering, but so far I can't come up with any other solution. I retrieve a model via axios. The model has a title (English) and may have (or may NOT) its own localized alternative title. The code below is working, but it prepends the localized title with '@' for some reason. So my question is how will I get rid of this '@'?

```
<label>
<span v-if="(ques.questionLocalized && ques.questionLocalized.{{\App::getLocale()}})">
@{{ques.questionLocalized.<?php echo \App::getLocale();?>}}
</span>  
<span v-else>@{{ques.question}}</span>
<small>({{__('ux.required')}})</small><span class="req">*</span>
</label>
```

[image][image]

Comment: are your views using `.blade` or `.vue`?

Comment: its laravel's blade

Comment: what happens if you remove `@`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `@verbatim` directive:

```
@verbatim
<label>
   <span v-if="(ques.questionLocalized && ques.questionLocalized. 
      {{\App::getLocale()}})">
      {{ques.questionLocalized.<?php echo \App::getLocale();?>}}
   </span>  
   <span v-else>{{ques.question}}</span>
   <small>({{__('ux.required')}})</small><span class="req">*</span>
</label>
@endverbatim
```

> you may wrap the HTML in the @verbatim directive so that you do not have to prefix each Blade echo statement with an @ symbol